# Using FFMpeg with Asp .Net Core and video stream

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, video, ffmpeg

I'm implementing an API that allows the user to send a video stream and generate thumbnails. I'm using ***asp.net core*** and ***Azure Blob Storage***. The interface of API is this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test_upload")]
    public IActionResult TestUpload( IFormFile mediaFile ) {
        //->store mediaFile
        //->generate thumbnail
        //->save thumbnail
        return Ok();
    }
```

I need to do two main things:

1. Generate a thumbnail
2. Get video information such as the duration

I tried to use libraries from Nuget, but all of this needs the file path and I don't have the file path, just the video Stream or the Blob from the Blob Storage after saving. So, my question is, how can I manage video directly from the stream using FFmpeg or another tool?

I know Azure Media Services provide a lot of tools to manage media files such as videos and audio, but it's too slow for videos that are just **2Mb and 30 seconds long**. And I don't need to encode the video, create streams or other things like that. I just need to take video information from a Stream and store the video on the Storage.

Any idea? Thanks!

**Update 1:**
I wrote a workaround by creating a folder for temporary videos, I just save the video in this folder, create the thumbnail and delete the temp file. But I don't know if this practice has some bad side effects.

Comment: I don't think it is possible directly from the stream or blob storage. But you could store the stream first on a 'normal' (temp) storage and do the processing there. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681552/verify-duration-of-video-which-has-been-uploaded-into-azure-blob

Comment: Ok thanks, with this method it works. But, it's a good pratice allow the server to save temp files in a folder? Can there be any side effects?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Poiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4998159/poiter), Posting your comment as an answer, which will be helpful to other community members.

> Upload to `%TEMP%` (which expands to `d:\local\temp`). That's local storage in App Service. All those libs should then work against the local filesystem, including [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)

> Cleanup your `%TEMP%` with a nightly WebJob to account for stale/incomplete uploads (i.e. remove files older than 6 hours), just in case your delete calls to the filesystem fail from time to time due to unforeseen reasons.

> Can there be any side effects?

Cache the input stream to temporary file. It brings seeking capability to live streams.
Please refer [FFmpeg Cache](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html)